# using mutate with row and column indexing and group by

Tags: r

I want to create a variable using dplyr that takes in a value conditional on another variable.

See example below.

```
data.frame(list(group=c('a','a','b','b'),
                time=c(1,2,1,2),
                value = seq(1,4,1))
```

I want to create a variable 'baseline' that takes the content of variable 'value' where time = 1 and by group. As such the desired output would be

```
data.frame(list(group=c('a','a','b','b'),
            time=c(1,2,1,2),
            value = seq(1,4,1),
            baseline = c(1,1,3,3)))
```

Tried to run the following code with indexing but am clearly going wrong somewhere

```
 x <- data.frame(list(group=c('a','a','b','b'),
                time=c(1,2,1,2),
                value = seq(1,4,1))


 x %>% group_by(group) %>% 
      mutate(baseline = .[[.$time==1,.$value]])
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need a `list` wrapper

Comment: The row/column indexing you mentioned won't work here because the column index (if it is from 'value' is 3 and 4 and your original data have only 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which.min`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(baseline = value[which.min(time)])
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group  time value baseline
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 a         1     1        1
#2 a         2     2        1
#3 b         1     3        3
#4 b         2     4        3
```

and if it is already ordered by 'time', then simply use `first`

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(baseline = first(value))
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  data.frame(group=c('a','a','b','b'),
              time=c(1,2,1,2),
            value = seq(1,4,1))
```